# serviceWorker y registerServiceWorker

Tags: reactjs

En una aplicación de React, figura en la carpeta src el archivo serviceWorker. Sin embargo en el desarrollo de la aplicación se hace referencia a registerServiceWorker.

De manera que al ejecutar la aplicación se genera el siguiente error:
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './registerServiceWorker' does not contain a default export (imported as 'registerServiceWorker').
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Muchas gracias.
Francisco

Comment: Saludos bro, bienvenido a SOes, agrega el código por favor. También revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas la primera medalla, dicho sea de paso, lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask te ayudará a redactar buenas preguntas. A más detalles, más fácil de dar solución :D

Comment: Hola. Lo siento pero no sé qué código tengo que agregar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Todo el que creas que ayudará a reproducir tu caso. Y si falta, la comunidad te dirá. Saludos :D

Comment: Te  dice que el archivo `.registerServiceWorker` no tiene un `export default`, si no que tiene un _named export_.